# How to find the center of a circle moving and rotating in space having the coords of 3 points on the circle?

Tags: trigonometry, circles, 3d, parametric

consider a circular plate with radius R , with three points on it at arbitrary coordinates on the plate area that form a triangle. Just imagine 3 holes on the plate area

If I can have the new coordinates of these 3 points when the circular plate translates and rotates in space, how can I find the new coordinates of the circle plate center in space ?

Comment: Three points determine a circle, but not a disk. Any disk containing the circle that is determined by the points would contain the points.

Comment: No , I corrected the question, these 3 points do not necessary always fall on one circle, they are holes in the disk area